# How to prevent save input history that begins with a space in PowerShell?

Tags: shell, powershell, input-history

In bash (at least in Ubuntu), it is possible not to save commands starting with a space in the history (HISTCONTROL).
Is there a way to get this feature in Powershell?

Comment: I don't think so. You can get and clear the history but I don't think you can omit certain items from it. [Check out the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/clear-history?view=powershell-6)

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will check. But this feature is very useful for quick simple calculation (for example, 2 + 2, 12654 * 13, etc.) or changing folders (cd) without saving them in history.

Comment: IMO that wouldn't make sense when pasting code with indents. Take a look at [PSReadLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/?view=powershell-5.1) **Hint** if you don't want some entries in the history, inspect `&(Get-PSReadLineOption).HistorySavePath` from time to time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since at least PowerShell 5.1 you can use [`Set-PSReadlineOption`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlineoption?view=powershell-5.1#parameters)'s `-AddToHistoryHandler` to validate if a command should be added to the history with a custom function.

> `-AddToHistoryHandler` Specifies a ScriptBlock that controls which commands get added to PSReadLine history.
>
> The ScriptBlock receives the command line as input. If the ScriptBlock
> returns `$True`, the command line is added to the history.

And for completeness, here is a code sample you can add to your `$PROFILE.CurrentUserAllHosts`

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -AddToHistoryHandler {
    param($command)
    if ($command -like ' *') {
        return $false
    }
    # Add any other checks you want
    return $true
}
```

Comment: While commands starting with a space won't be saved to the file `(Get-PSReadLineOption).HistorySavePath`, it does not affect the command `Get-History`.  Entries beginning with space will still be outputed.

Comment: Interesting comment. Indeed, `Get-History` does return the command with the leading space. I do not know how `Get-History` is really used, because when using the arrow up or `Control P` or `Control R` to recall recent commands, the command is not shown.

Comment: Found the simpler syntax over here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64256603/1213346 so updated the answer.